# App crashes while using Shareactionprovider

Tags: android, android-intent, android-actionbar, photo

I created an app which uses camera in which when user takes a photo he is provided with `Shareactionprovider`(**Api level 16+**) to share the image...

Since the `shareactionprovider` has to appear after the user takes the photo it must be in `onPrepareoptionsmenu()`...

I used the following code but the app crashes....**If i dont use** `onPrepareoptionsmenu()` the **app works fine** but then i cant get the Shareactionprovider

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.camera, menu);
    return true;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.camera, menu);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_share);
        // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item
                .getActionProvider();
        doShare();
        Toast.makeText(this, "prepare", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
public void doShare() {
    try {
        if (file.exists() && file.length() > 0) {
            // Populate the share intent with data
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            mImageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, mImageUri);
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);
        } else
            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "You cancelled the image capture!!!! Please take image in order to Share",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please take image in order to Share",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

What am i going wrong?

Comment: Can you please share the logcat crash trace?

Answer (score 0):

Got it...Actually i didn't realize that the shareactionprovider was working only after the options menu was reloaded(Pressing the menu key in my case)...